# Batch File Querying Registry in 64-Bit Vista

Tags: batch-file, scripting, 64-bit, registry

Hi guys me again :) I have a problem with a batch file I wrote. It works fine on 32-bit, but apparently it doesn't work on 64-bit systems, and I don't know why because I do not have access to a 64-bit system.

This is the code that works on Vista 32-bit system

```
    @echo off
Set Reg.Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware
  Set Reg.Val=InstallPath
  For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
   'Reg Query "%Reg.Key%" /v "%Reg.Val%" ^| Find /I "%Reg.Val%"'
  ) Do Call Set MBAMPATH=%%B
```

Can someone re-write it to work on a 64-bit please?

Thanks always :)

Answer (score 6):

There's no difference between batch files on x86 and x64 versions of Windows. The problem you have is due to WoW64 and transparent Registry redirection, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459) for more details.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` is the correct registry key for 32bit software on a 64bit installation of Windows, and this code works on my machine:

```
Set Reg.Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware
Set Reg.Val=InstallPath
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "%Reg.Key%" /v "%Reg.Val%" ^| Find /I "%Reg.Val%"' )
Do Call Set MBAMPATH=%%B
echo %mbampath%
```

Your other post includes a conditional branch based on the %processor_architecture% environment variable. The problem with that is that (on my machine at least) `%processor_architecture%` is `"AMD64"` not `"x64"`.

Why not just query both possible registry keys rather than branching based on architecture?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is nothing I know which would be different for batch files on 64-bit Windows compared to 32 bit.

You might try removing `echo off` from the start to see which line produces which error message (assuming you see any).

However, maybe something clashes with the apostrophes you have used in the `for` loop. You could try changing it to

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%A in (`Reg Query "%Reg.Key%" /v "%Reg.Val%" ^| Find /I "%Reg.Val%"`) Do Call Set MBAMPATH=%%B
```

And while we're at it. Why do you `call` `set` there? That isn't necessary, so you could remove it as well:

```
... do set MBAMPATH=%%B
```

Comment: Apparently it has somethin' to do with installing MBAM on a 64bit OS, it is installed in the "Program Files (x86)" folder. That it was my mate said to me, he is on a 64-bit OS, and is gettin' errors in the script. 

The key for MBAM is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware

But me just changing the line on the file to that reg key doesn't seem to work for him either, the installpath is not set to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem where I needed to know the Notepad++ install directory. If it is on a x64 OS then I need to look in the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++ reg key. The reason I don't look for arch of the processor is that you can put a 32 bit OS on a 64bit capable machine. This is the code I came up with and seems to find the right path for me:

:: find out if x86 or x64 OS - need different reg key to query for install dir
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" goto X64
ELSE goto X86

:X64
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++" ')DO SET NPPPath="%%B\plugins\APIs"
echo The NPPPath is %NPPPath%
SET BITNESS="SixtyFour"
goto CopyAPIFile

:X86
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Notepad++" ')DO SET NPPPath="%%B\plugins\APIs"
:: echo The NPPPath is %NPPPath%
SET BITNESS="ThirtyTwo"
goto CopyAPIFile

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).