# variable from registry (batch files)

Tags: variables, path, batch-file, registry, set

I am making a little mod for the old game sims 1, and i thought i make a simple batch file for installing it, just to be fancy.
anyway, in the registry you can find the installpath

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Maxis\The Sims]
"InstallPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Maxis\\The Sims"
```

now, i need this to be a variable in my bat file, like

```
set simsdir=%installpath%
```

how do i do this? ive googled it but it made no sense what so ever to me so, thats why i am asking here :p

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to call [reg.exe](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregistry.php)

The accepted answer on [771240](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771240/batch-file-querying-registry-in-64-bit-vista/771558#771558) looks to have the syntax you'll need. I've not tested this, but it should look something like

```
Set Reg.Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Maxis\The Sims
Set Reg.Val=InstallPath
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "%Reg.Key%" /v "%Reg.Val%" ^| Find /I "%Reg.Val%"' )
Do Call Set simsdir=%%B
echo %simsdir%
```

*edit*

Maybe try it with the for all on the one line, that's the only way I could get it to work. I'm a bit rusty on the 'ol batch files though

```
Set Reg.Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Maxis\The Sims
Set Reg.Val=InstallPath

For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%Reg.Key%" /v "%Reg.Val%" ^| Find /I "%Reg.Val%"' ) Do Call Set simsdir=%%B
echo %simsdir%
```

Comment: afai understand it, i need to reg export it to a txt file, then make the bat file read the specific line of the txt, and then make that the variable. i just dont know how to do this :)

Comment: I edited the answer to have an example. From what I understand, you don't need the intermediate text file, you can For loop directly over the output of Reg.exe