# How to fetch data with a batch file from registry?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need my batch file to fetch the path listed in the following directory within registry -

`\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MapNetWorkDriveMRU`

I referred to several posts but it doesn't seem to work for my situation.

for e.g: 
[variable from registry (batch files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866326/variable-from-registry-batch-files)

the expected result should show the path listed in the `MapNetworkDriveMRU`

Answer (score 1):

This Worked For Me. - Taken From [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6866499/8667430).

```
@ECHO OFF

Set "Reg.Key=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MapNetworkDriveMRU"
Set "Reg.Val=StringName"

For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%Reg.Key%" /v "%Reg.Val%" ^| Find /I "%Reg.Val%"') Do (Call Set "dir=%%B")
echo %dir%

pause
```

Comment: If it was taken from another post you should have commented or flagged it as a duplicate, not replicate it?